# bootstrap-vue: most Icons isnt showing

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I import **all** icons (as documentation says):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, BootstrapVueIcons } from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons)
```

When I copy some code from site - icon is working great.

This example is ok:

```
<b-icon icon="exclamation-circle-fill" variant="info"></b-icon>
```

But when Im just changing the icon name, it disappears... It looks like some icons does not exist...

This doesnt work:

```
<b-icon icon="cart" variant="info"></b-icon>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: This [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-frost-k4ceb) seems to work. Can you edit it to reproduce the problem?

Comment: yep. but the same code doesnt work locally ( I see first icon, but I dont see second one (cart)...

Comment: It may be caused by incompatible bootstrap-vue version, can you show your package.json?

Comment: "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.14.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",

Comment: after updating to 2.15 icons work great! Would you like to post your comment as an answer? I will checked it as answered.

Comment: @tony19 Your demo shows that the problem DOES exist. Try changing the icon to `send` for example, you will notice that it does not display. Try this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-violet-xrwyss?file=/App.vue

Comment: @keyboard-warrior There is [no `send` icon defined in `BootstrapVueIcons`](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/icons/icons.js). You should file an issue requesting that they re-generate their icons list.

Comment: anyway, it is better to use Quasar ) Vuetify and VueBootstrap are boring )