# some vue bootstrap-vue icons not working with nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Nuxt with [bootstarp-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) so far all the components are working as expected. but some bootstrap-vue icons are not showing up

index.vue

```
<b-icon-arrow-up></b-icon-arrow-up>
<b-icon icon="bar-chart-fill"></b-icon>
<b-icon icon="cart"></b-icon>
```

nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
],
bootstrapVue: {
    icons: true,
},
```

Both `b-icon-arrow-up` and `b-icon icon="bar-chart-fill"` are working and coming as SVG in to the DOM. It's only the `b-icon icon="cart"` SVG tag has an empty `g` in it. I've also tried with a couple of more icons as well camera, slash-circle are coming and alarm, back icons are not coming just like cart.

I have also tried to pull cart as a single component from the bootstarp-vue like this,

```
import { BIcon, BIconCart } from 'bootstrap-vue'
.....
export default {
  components: {
    BIcon,
    BIconCart
  },
....
```

which didn't work either I just got an error saying the component `BIconCart` is not found

Comment: what is the version you are using ?related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097264/bootstrap-vue-most-icons-isnt-showing

Comment: This still happens when using Vue Bootstrap latest version. Some icons just don't appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `BootstrapVue` you're using probably doesn't have the icon you're looking for, so try updating `BootstrapVue` to the latest version.

You can see which version of BootstrapVue contains which version of Bootstrap-Icons on the icons page https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/icons.

Current reference as of this post:

- Bootstrap Icons were introduced to BootstrapVue in release v2.2.0.
- Bootstrap Icons v1.0.0-alpha3 were added in BootstrapVue v2.8.0.
- Bootstrap Icons v1.0.0-alpha4 were added in BootstrapVue v2.15.0.
- Bootstrap Icons v1.0.0-alpha5 were added in BootstrapVue v2.16.0.
- Bootstrap Icons v1.0.0 were added in BootstrapVue v2.17.0.
- Bootstrap Icons v1.1.0 were added in BootstrapVue v2.19.0.
- Bootstrap Icons v1.2.0 were added in BootstrapVue v2.21.0.